# Nested events triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about a code like the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var checkboxCnt = 1;
  var checkboxHtml =
    `<br><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox${checkboxCnt}">` +
    `<label for="checkbox${checkboxCnt}">Checkbox 1</label>`;

  // ******************************************
  $('div :checkbox').change(function(e) {
    checkboxChanged(e);
  });
  // ******************************************

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    checkboxCnt++;
    checkboxHtml = checkboxHtml.replaceAll(checkboxCnt - 1, checkboxCnt);
    $(this).before($(checkboxHtml));

    // ******************************************
    $('div :checkbox').change(function(e) {
      checkboxChanged(e);
    });
    // ******************************************
  });

  function checkboxChanged(e) {
    var checkboxID = '#' + e.target.id;
    if ($(checkboxID).is(':checked')) {
      console.log(checkboxID + ' is checked');
    } else {
      console.log(checkboxID + ' is unchecked');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
  <button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Sample can be found on https://jsfiddle.net/da7wLukz/.

This is just a simplified version of the code I'm currently editing, and it adds a checkbox every time when you hit the button. I want to execute something every time when the checkboxes are (un)checked, but I've come across the problem that when you have 4 checkboxes and check the checkbox4, the change event is triggered only once but when you check the checkbox3, it's triggered twice, and when you check the checkbox2, it's triggered 3 times and so on. The code has the same lines inside and outside of $('#btn).click because, let's say we don't have the $('div :checkbox).change event inside the $('#btn).click event, then the change event isn't triggered when checkbox2, 3, 4... are checked.

I just want the change event to be triggered only once when I (un)check the checkbox, but how can I do this? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't nest event handlers. Use unobtrusive event handling via `$(document).on()` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)):

```js
$(function() {
  var checkboxCnt = 0;
  var checkboxHtml =
    `<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox$%%">` +
    `<label for="checkbox$%%">Checkbox %%</label><br>`;
    
  function addCheckbox() {
    checkboxCnt++;
    $("#btn").before(checkboxHtml.replaceAll('%%', checkboxCnt));
  }

  $(document).on('change', 'div :checkbox', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      console.log(this.id + ' is checked');
    } else {
      console.log(this.id + ' is unchecked');
    }
  });

  $('#btn').click(addCheckbox);
  addCheckbox();
});
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<div>
  <button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the point of wrapping it in an ```$(function() {})```?

Comment: @seriously jQuery 101 - this waits until the document is ready. (And the wrapper function prevents the contains functions and variables from polluting the global space.)

Comment: yeah, I get that but why on this code cant OP just include script after dom?

Comment: @seriously I'm not getting into a discussion why the OP did or did not do a certain thing, or whether `$()` is necessary or not. `$()` is good practice, and it has zero drawbacks.

Comment: "it has zero drawbacks". Thats what I wanted to know thanks.

Comment: @seriously There is no performance penalty, and without it, you'd *still* have to wrap the whole thing in a function in order to prevent namespace pollution - but you'd have to manage load order manually (by explicitly placing the code after the body). With `$()` load order is managed for you, and the namespace pollution is prevented. Win-win.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tomalak. it worked like a charm. Anyway, I need the $(document).ready wrapper because my original script (that is much more complicated) is run on a webpage that loads a lot of other modules (including API). and my script will want to manipulate elements on the page; to do so the page needs to be ready, and this is why.

Comment: @Dragoniez `$(document).ready()` and `$()` are the same thing, I merely used the shorthand form.

Comment: @Tomalak Yep, I just thought I'd say something about what seriously mentioned :)